# Laravel Scope and Search results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working with laravel 5.5 and I made scope for my products in `Product.php` model:

```
public function scopeApproved($query)
{
    return $query->where('publish', 1);
}
```

*Taken from laravel website.*

Then I have this code below to show my search results.

```
public function search()
{
    $search = request('search');
    $searchType = request('searchType');

    if (strcmp($searchType, "posts") == 0) {
        $posts = Post::where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->get();
    } elseif (strcmp($searchType, "products") == 0) {
        $products = Product::where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->get();
    }

    return view('frontend.search', compact('posts', 'products'));
}
```

The problem with that is even if my product `publish` column is set to `0` still will pop in search results.

> same goes for products list, still shows in website.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You need to apply the scope. `Product::approved()->where(...)`

Comment: @jfadich still shows in results.

Comment: @mafortis because you are not utilize the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are adding local scope rather the global scope.

You can still use you local scope doing `Product::approved()`

But for global scope you need to create boot method in your `Product.php` like so:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('publish', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->where('publish', 1);
    });
}
```

if you want product  without global scope `Product::withoutGlobalScopes()->get();`

That should do it.

Also have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: Where do I make that global scope? is there any artisan command for it or what?

Comment: As this will only apply to this model i suggest you to create it inside your Product model.

Comment: `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Product::App\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given,`

Comment: you Builder should use `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;`

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159102/discussion-between-usrnotfound-and-mafortis

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public function search()
{
    $search = request('search');
    $searchType = request('searchType');

    if (strcmp($searchType, "posts") == 0) {
        $posts = Post::approved()->where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->get();
    } elseif (strcmp($searchType, "products") == 0) {
        $products = Product::approved()->where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->get();
    }

    return view('frontend.search', compact('posts', 'products'));
}
```

Comment: same result still shows products with `publish` value of `0`